# Откуда NullPointerException в тернарном операторе

Tags: java, тернарный-оператор

Вот есть у меня метод, который отлично работает:

```
public static Integer update(Integer val) {
    if (val == null)
        return val;
    else
        return val+1;
}
```

Передашь `null` — вернёт `null`, а иначе вернёт число на единицу больше.

Решил я его сократить, воспользовавшись тернарным оператором `?:`. Чтобы точно не накосячить я даже не стал это делать вручную, а попросил Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse refactoring]

Получился такой метод:

```
public static Integer update(Integer val) {
    return val == null ? val : val+1;
}
```

И он после этого перестал работать! Если передаёшь `null`, он не возвращает `null`, а падает с `NullPointerException`! Почему так? Вроде бы тернарный оператор — то же самое, что `if/else`?

Comment: Вот всегда нутром чувствовал, что Java -- *неправильная вещь*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Дело в том, что тернарный оператор -- это выражение, которое имеет определённый конкретный тип возвращаемого значения, поэтому обе его ветки должны возвращать объект этого типа.

Для выражения `val == null ? val : val+1` компилятор выводит тип `int`, потому что во второй ветке производится сложение объекта `Integer` со значением типа `int`, которое преобразуется в `val.intValue() + 1`, т.е. выполняется unboxing переменной `val`. Так как вторая ветка имеет тип `int`, для результата первой ветки тоже будет предпринята попытка выполнить unboxing, и в итоге метод будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public static Integer update(Integer val) {
    return Integer.valueOf(val == null ? val.intValue() : val.intValue() + 1);
}
```

Легко заметить, что если `val` будет иметь значение `null`, то возникнет исключение `NullPointerException`.

---

Это можно исправить двумя способами:

1. Явно обозначить, что вторая часть выражения имеет тип `Integer`. Это позволит сделать так, чтобы не требовался unboxing первой ветки (т.е. результатом всего выражения будет `Integer`). Это то, что предлагает IntelliJ IDEA при попытке рефакторинга первоначального выражения:

   ```
   public static Integer update(Integer val) {
       return val == null ? val : Integer.valueOf(val + 1);
   }
   ```

   В этом случае будет сгенерирован следующий код:

   ```
   public static Integer update(Integer val) {
       return val == null ? val : Integer.valueOf(val.intValue() + 1);
   }
   ```

   т.е. unboxing будет выполнен только во второй ветке, после чего результат будет снова упакован в `Integer`, а в первой ветке уже имеется `Integer`, поэтому можно не выполнять с ним никаких действий и значение `null` пройдёт без приключений.
2. Показать, что мы просто возвращаем `null` в первой ветке:

   ```
   public static Integer update(Integer val) {
       return val == null ? null : val + 1;
   }
   ```

   В этом случае boxing второй ветки писать явно не требуется, так как компилятор сразу будет знать, что выражение не может иметь примитивный тип. Это преобразуется в следующий код:

   ```
   public static Integer update(Integer val) {
       return val == null ? null : Integer.valueOf(val.intValue() + 1);
   }
   ```

   Как видно, boxing и unboxing производятся только во второй части выражения. Я считаю, что этот вариант предпочтительнее ещё и потому, что здесь явно видно, что мы возвращаем `null`, а не просто `val`, и не требуется раскручивать выражение для понимания этого факта.

---

Как можно догадаться, оператор `if ... else ...` подобным поведением не обладает и в случае с ним такой проблемы не возникает, достаточно уже, что все `return` возвращают объекты, приводимые к типу `Integer`.

Comment: Ладно, пойдёт. Хотя подходящая цитата из спецификации была бы уместна :-)